# Where are Docker images stored on the host machine?

Tags: docker, docker-image

I managed to find the containers under directory `/var/lib/docker/containers`, but I can't find the images.

What are the directories and files under `/var/lib/docker`?

Comment: Best to state specifics of operating system in the question title and/or questions statement in such cases. Two good answers were provided for linux and macOS (Mac OS X).

Answer (score 716, accepted):

The contents of the `/var/lib/docker` directory vary depending on the [driver Docker is using for storage](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/990a3e30fa66e7bd3df3c78c873c97c5b1310486/daemon/graphdriver/driver.go#L37-L43).

By default this will be `aufs` but can fall back to `overlay`, `overlay2`, `btrfs`, `devicemapper` or `zfs` depending on your kernel support. In most places this will be `aufs` but the [RedHats went with `devicemapper`](http://developerblog.redhat.com/2014/09/30/overview-storage-scalability-docker/).

You can manually set the storage driver with the [`-s` or `--storage-driver=`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#/daemon-storage-driver-option) option to the [Docker daemon](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/).

- `/var/lib/docker/{driver-name}` will contain the driver specific storage for contents of the images.
- `/var/lib/docker/graph/<id>` now only contains metadata about the image, in the `json` and `layersize` files.

In the case of `aufs`:

- `/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/<id>` has the file contents of the images.
- `/var/lib/docker/repositories-aufs` is a JSON file containing local image information. This can be viewed with the command `docker images`.

In the case of `devicemapper`:

- `/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data` stores the images
- `/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata` the metadata
- Note these files are thin provisioned "sparse" files so aren't as big as they seem.

Comment: Ftr: Debian `stretch/sid` uses `devicemapper` too.

Comment: Can I see the content inside, by mounting it in some way?

Comment: If you set the storage driver after it is already running and has some running containers with images, will it migrate the date on the next restart of the daemon?  If not then how to modify the storage driver in this case?

Comment: For MacOS, [see answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37642236/1618202)

Comment: Shameless self-plug: you can use the [filepie](https://github.com/marcodiiga/filepie) utility to visualize and navigate through the contents of `docker/aufs` and see how the storage is organized.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and don't "check defaults". Use `docker info` and find the actual location **specific to your setup**.

Comment: I'm seeing overlay2 instead of devicemapper. So i've looked into /var/lib/docker/overlay2 and didn't find anything

Comment: I have the JSON image information file at `/var/lib/docker/image/aufs/repositories.json`. Using Docker version 17.09.0-ce with `aufs` driver.

Comment: CentOS 7.6, docker-ce 18.09.0 uses overlay2

Comment: This seems to have changed. I am using `Docker for Mac` with 2 images of 1.5 GB each and `/var/lib` has no directory `docker`.

Comment: on linux this is configured in daemon config file: `/etc/docker/daemon.json`
https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/

`{    "data-root": "/mnt/docker-data",    "storage-driver": "overlay2" }`

Comment: With specific default path, one can always change the docker storage path in daemon.json with ""data-root": "/var/app/docker/mypath/storage""

Answer (score 327):

When using Docker for Mac Application, it appears that the containers are stored within the VM located at:

```
~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/Docker.qcow2
```

**UPDATE** (Courtesy of [mmorin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9251158/mmorin)):

As of Jan 15 2019 it seems there is only this file:

```
~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/Docker.raw
```

that contains the Docker Disk and all the images and containers within it.

Comment: Is this the location for all images (like `ubuntu`, `nginx`), or is this the location for all containers? The original question asks for **images**, not **containers**...

Comment: If you keep in mind that Docker is still running in a VM, the system paths are relative to the VM and not from the Mac Osx system. Try this command : docker run --rm -it -v /:/vm-root alpine:edge ls -l /vm-root nad after this : docker run --rm -it -v /:/vm-root alpine:edge ls -l /vm-root/var/lib/docker    You are available to list the docker folder from the WM host

Comment: This seems to have changed. I am using `Docker for Mac` with two images of 1.5 GB each and `~/Library/Containers/Data/com.docker.docker/Data` has no directory `com.docker.driver.amd64-linux` and the only big file is in `vms/0/Docker.raw` with 3.6 GB.

Comment: Whether qcow2 or raw is used depends on whether you are at MacOS High Sierra with APFS or below: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/faqs/#disk-usage

Comment: Check size for mac: `du -hd1  ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/`

Comment: As for 2.1.0.4 (of Docker Desktop) location is slightly different (extra `data`): `~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/data/Docker.raw`

Comment: A usefull addition to this post is a blog post:
https://timonweb.com/posts/getting-path-and-accessing-persistent-volumes-in-docker-for-mac/

Answer (score 143):

Actually, Docker images are stored in two files as shown by following command

```
$ docker info
```

> Data file: `/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data`
>
> Metadata file: `/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata`

Comment: This is for RedHat variants. They [chose not to go AUFS as it's not in the mainline kernel](http://developerblog.redhat.com/2014/09/30/overview-storage-scalability-docker/).

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, these two lines "(Meta)data file" do not appear in every docker. It depends on the driver used

Comment: @DmitryYudin [mirosval's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234831/where-are-docker-images-stored-on-the-host-machine#37642236) works for latest [Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/).

Comment: A proper answer is not "This is where it is on MY machine." A proper answer is "Here is **how you find it** on YOUR machine." This is a proper answer. I joined a company with 11 different EBS volumes full of docker images. This answer allowed me to figure out which was the **current** "Root Dir".

Comment: On Mac OS X (at least on Yosemite, which is EOL w.r.t. Docker), `docker info` is very useful, but the output `Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker` does not indicate the image storage location (see Mac-specific answer above).

Comment: This is out of date for CentOS 7.5.

Comment: This works in Google Cloud - Ubuntu version. I could find the images in /var/lib/docker/overlay2

Comment: I don't see the said attributes in `docker info` on MacOS Catalina 10.15

Comment: `docker info | grep /` tells you the location. It can be moved from default!

Answer (score 128):

**this was the old way of doing, now it has changed. Disregard this answer as of 2019**

In the special case of Mac OS X or Windows, using boot2docker, your Docker images are stored within a VirtualBox VM managed by boot2docker.

This VM will be stored in normal place of VirtualBox images:

OS X: `~/VirtualBox VMs/boot2docker-vm`

Windows: `%USERPROFILE%/VirtualBox VMs/boot2docker-vm`

You can reset it by running (WARNING: This will destroy all images you've built and downloaded so far):

```
boot2docker down
boot2docker destroy
boot2docker init
boot2docker up
```

This is especially useful if you kept tons of intermediate images when building / debugging a build without the useful --rm options, I quote them here for reference:
Use:

```
docker build -t webapp --rm=true --force-rm=true .
```

instead of:

```
docker build -t webapp .
```

Comment: Docker shuffled things around I believe, so now `boot2docker` results in  `command not found` -- thoughts?

Comment: Following a new install of Docker on Windows 10, I can confirm that the result of clicking the Docker Quickstart Terminal shortcut for the first time creates a virtual machine (VM) called 'default' (after a couple of unsuccessful starts - keep running it until it works). This 'default' VM can be located within Windows at:


`%USERPROFILE%\.docker\machine\machines`


(please note the full stop in the path)

Comment: In newer releases **boot2docker** is now **docker-machine**. See https://docs.docker.com/machine/migrate-to-machine/

Comment: Is it possible to change that location?

Comment: Now that Docker has moved to **docker-machine** I can't locate the image folder on Windows 10. The folder `%USERPROFILE%\.docker` doesn't exist.

Comment: The answer is no longer correct for Windows 10. Instead, see the newer answer from @tristan which references `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks\MobyLinuxVM.vhdx`

Comment: %USERPROFILE%\.docker is still correct for win7 setups.

Comment: This answer is super old, and needs to be updated. -- Docker on Windows is definitely not using VirtualBox (you can see the VM in Hyper-V, which would have to be disabled for VirtualBox to even run...)

Answer (score 77):

On the newly released 'Docker for Windows', which uses Hyper-V, data is located in the Docker virtual hard disk:

```
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks\MobyLinuxVM.vhdx
```

You can also open the 'Hyper-V Manager' for access to the Docker / MobyLinuxVM.

Comment: Docker on Windows 10 Anniversary Update puts image files in `C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter` for me.  More info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39971954/188740

Comment: 'Hyper-V Manager'  is the answer !

Comment: I don't have Hyper V and I am using Docker Toolbox .. Any idea where the virtual disk will be

Comment: -- I have a file in `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\data\ext4.vhdx` 1.6GB (& `\Docker\wsl\distro\ext4.vhdx` 105MB). not sure if thats the image. (Im not using Hyper-V, but WSL 2.)

-- (-- I tried many other answers, those folders locations like `var/lib/docker`, `overlay2`, `DockerDesktop`, just either none exist / doesnt contain the image files, in my Window OS. 

-- Though, 
`$ docker info` does show `Storage Driver: overlay2`; & 
`$ docker inspect container_id` does show `"MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4zxxxxxxpb/merged"`. 

-- I have no idea why.)

Answer (score 75):

The images are stored in `/var/lib/docker/graph/<id>/layer`.

Note that images are just diffs from the parent image. The parent ID is stored with the image's metadata `/var/lib/docker/graph/<id>/json`.

When you `docker run` an image. AUFS will 'merge' all layers into one usable file system.

Comment: This answer is now out of date, they've moved things around.

Comment: @Air Can you post what has moved around?

Comment: there is no graph folder anymore

Answer (score 60):

On Ubuntu you can "play" with images running

```
sudo baobab /var/lib/docker
```

Actually, images are stored within `/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff`

[image: screenshot showing disk analyzer tool baobab running on /var/lib/docker]

Comment: Nice indeed. On Mac DaisyDisk is similar (wheel display), GrandPerspective also useful (rectangles).

Comment: It seems it is the only reliable way to find it.

Answer (score 51):

For someone who is using Docker toolbox (that uses docker-machine), the answers concerning boot2docker on Mac OS X is not valid. The docker-machine VM is called "default" and it exists in the `/Users/<username>/.docker/machine/machines/default/` directory.

Comment: I can't find any containers or images folders inside that directory.

Comment: look for disk.vmdk in that directory

Comment: $docker images -a yields around 1 gig of images, while disk.vmdk in ~/.docker is around 20 gigs. How come?

Comment: Where it is stored in Windows ?

Comment: @Grav: The virtual machine allocates 20 gigs for future use, but only uses 1 gig for images.

Comment: So in my case, the downloaded images are stored inside the disk.vmdk file (I'm using Mac OSX + VirtualBox). Destroying this VB machine and deleting its files, will delete all the images as well.

Answer (score 24):

In **Docker for Windows** (native Windows) the default container storage is at:

```
   > docker info
   ...
   Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\Docker
   ...
```

Comment: I ran the `docker build` command & I don't see a file which I think is the image file.  I see some folders and some text files (e.g. service.txt).  What type of file & with what file extension does the `docker build` create?

Comment: it is not there

Comment: @akashmaurya did you run `docker info`?

Answer (score 23):

If you are using Docker for MAC (not `boot2docker`) then the location is `/Users/<</>UserName></>/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/`

Comment: Yeah, when I did a: `jasper@~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux $ ls -lh | grep Docker
-rw-r--r--@ 1 jasper  staff   6.3G May 25 19:20 Docker.qcow2` I found the image. But that is not the containers though. Do not see them in this Data directory really..

Comment: But as stated before you here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37642236/460885 it is inside this image that the containers are located.

Answer (score 13):

```
sudo docker info | grep -e "Root Dir"
```

Answer (score 8):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38792709/529403), if you're on Mac, it is located at

```
/Users/MyUserName/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/Docker.qcow2
```

Comment: Docker.qcow2? How am i suppose to pull a specific docker image from that?

Answer (score 8):

Expanding on Tristan's answer, in Windows with Hyper-V you can move the image with these [steps](https://forums.docker.com/t/where-are-images-stored/9794/7) from matthuisman:

> In Windows 10,
>
> 1. Stop docker etc
> 2. Type "Hyper-V Manager" in task-bar search box and run it.
> 3. Select your PC in the left hand pane (Mine is called
>      DESKTOP-CBP**)
> 4. Right click on the correct virtual machine (Mine is
>      called MobyLinuxVM)
> 5. Select "Turn off" (If it is running)
> 6. Right click on it again and select "Move"
> 7. Follow the prompts

Comment: This only moves the Hyper-V machine not the images, the images would still be stored where the VHD location is.

Comment: @olive_tree I'm trying to find the images created by `docker build` command.  I'm on a Windows 10 computer.  I look in C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks, but all I see is MobyLinuxVM.vhdx.  Where are the actual images stored?

Answer (score 8):

Use [`docker info`](https://docs.docker.com/edge/engine/reference/commandline/info/) command to display system-wide information and the location may vary.

> Depending on the storage driver in use, additional information can be shown, such as pool name, data file, metadata file, data space used, total data space, metadata space used, and total metadata space.
>
> The data file is where the images are stored and the metadata file is where the meta data regarding those images are stored. When run for the first time Docker allocates a certain amount of data space and meta data space from the space available on the volume where `/var/lib/docker` is mounted.

Here is the example on Ubuntu (check *Root Dir*):

```
$ docker info
...
Server Version: 18.06.1-ce
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/aufs
...
Docker Root Dir: /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker
...
```

And here is the example on Travis CI (see *Docker Root Dir*):

```
$ docker info
Server Version: 17.09.0-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
...
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
...
```

You can use `--format` parameter to extract that information into a single file, e.g.

```
$ docker info --format '{{.DriverStatus}}'
[[Root Dir /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/aufs] [Backing Filesystem extfs] [Dirs 265] [Dirperm1 Supported true]]
```

or:

```
$ docker info --format '{{json .DriverStatus}}'
[["Root Dir","/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/aufs"],["Backing Filesystem","extfs"],["Dirs","265"],["Dirperm1 Supported","true"]]
```

Comment: Do you know why when using `docker pull` this does not ask for user password despite the directory `/var/lib/docker` and its subdirectories are only readable/writable by root? I already have  my user in docker group, but I wonder how is it possible to download images if only root has access

Answer (score 8):

For "Docker Desktop", click on docker system tray icon and click "Settings".

[image]

On the Advanced tab, you can see the disk image location.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you keep in mind that Docker is still running in a VM, the system paths are relative to the VM and not from the Mac Osx system. 
As it says all is contained in a VM file :

> /Users/MyUserName/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/Docker.qcow2

Try to run Alpine image with this volume option and the ls command you are able to list the VM host:

> docker run --rm -it -v /:/vm-root alpine:edge ls -l /vm-root

After this just try :

> docker run --rm -it -v /:/vm-root alpine:edge ls -l
>   /vm-root/var/lib/docker

Now, you are able to list the docker folder from the VM host

Comment: Thanks! This is the only answer that worked for me on Windows 10 with Hyper-v. I was able to clean up the corrupted files under the elusive /var/lib/docker/overlay2 folder.

Answer (score 7):

use `docker inspect container_id`
find folder under MergedDir

```
# example. 
"MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f40cc2ea8912ec3b32deeef5a1542a132f6e918acb/merged
```

Comment: this is the best dev-friendly way to let Docker tell us where it's getting the image from!

Answer (score 5):

I use the boot2docker for Docker on Mac OSX, so the images is stored into the `/Users/<USERNAME>/VirtualBox VMs/boot2docker-vm/boot2docker-vm.vmdk`.

Answer (score 5):

In Docker for Windows, the logs are here: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Docker`

Answer (score 5):

I can answer this question only for Ubuntu users:

The root directory of docker can be found when you run the command `docker info`

Docker directory will be given in this line: "`Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker`"

About the docker images, they are stored inside the docker directory: 
`/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/`

Remember these things are not same in all version of docker. Currently, I am using 1.12.3.

Answer (score 5):

**ENV**

OS: `fedora 29 x86_64 workstation`

Docker:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea838
```

Image info: `"DockerVersion": "18.09.7"`

---

The images should stored in `/var/lib/docker/overlay2` by default.

---

**MY EXAMPLE**

Show images:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
neo4j               latest              8ed7463b8476        12 months ago       548MB
hello-world         latest              fce289e99eb9        2 years ago         1.84kB
```

The image size is 548M.

See the image information of `8ed7463b8476`.

```
[user@localhost ~]$ docker image inspect 8ed7463b8476
```

```
... ... ... ...

"DockerVersion": "18.09.7",

... ... ... ...

"GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2
/66dc24704d7ea5f1a5dee0bf4a5297cb78bcbd0d4b36206b8cca62cd4de7f2b1/diff:
/var/lib/docker/overlay2
/5ab91cf721359d43d01038233d397fd9ed1c4b3857c0c7d9a2dd7f2ac5eccad0/diff:
/var/lib/docker/overlay2
/e82fdf7ee3e37db0a11d9ca309245ae852425d24d6f5d3313dcf604cdddb397b/diff:
/var/lib/docker/overlay2
/9394543085d467010d0468fffb388e5616a89e2cf16c1c2b7b31aee4e542ae69/diff:
/var/lib/docker/overlay2
/c7c7a16e3dbaeea1a3a3b0bbca39f34f08f6b8ab15d753e6e68f9851c80d95b4/diff:
/var/lib/docker/overlay2
/3b470afdf8939b45159f3171f0bef2a27085b4b980e09f0c666fbdc58b944d97/diff:
/var/lib/docker/overlay2
/463ba63f79eb6b2f5466e7b71041bc346a8e9c4ebddd34d23422c719824a2340/diff",

... ... ... ...
```

Let's see the size of these folders.

```
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo du -sh /var/lib/docker/overlay2/66dc24704d7ea5f1a5dee0bf4a5297cb78bcbd0d4b36206b8cca62cd4de7f2b1
141M    /var/lib/docker/overlay2/66dc24704d7ea5f1a5dee0bf4a5297cb78bcbd0d4b36206b8cca62cd4de7f2b1
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo du -sh /var/lib/docker/overlay2/5ab91cf721359d43d01038233d397fd9ed1c4b3857c0c7d9a2dd7f2ac5eccad0/
28K /var/lib/docker/overlay2/5ab91cf721359d43d01038233d397fd9ed1c4b3857c0c7d9a2dd7f2ac5eccad0/
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo du -sh /var/lib/docker/overlay2/e82fdf7ee3e37db0a11d9ca309245ae852425d24d6f5d3313dcf604cdddb397b/
100K    /var/lib/docker/overlay2/e82fdf7ee3e37db0a11d9ca309245ae852425d24d6f5d3313dcf604cdddb397b/
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo du -sh /var/lib/docker/overlay2/9394543085d467010d0468fffb388e5616a89e2cf16c1c2b7b31aee4e542ae69/
310M    /var/lib/docker/overlay2/9394543085d467010d0468fffb388e5616a89e2cf16c1c2b7b31aee4e542ae69/
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo du -sh /var/lib/docker/overlay2/c7c7a16e3dbaeea1a3a3b0bbca39f34f08f6b8ab15d753e6e68f9851c80d95b4/
36K /var/lib/docker/overlay2/c7c7a16e3dbaeea1a3a3b0bbca39f34f08f6b8ab15d753e6e68f9851c80d95b4/
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo du -sh /var/lib/docker/overlay2/3b470afdf8939b45159f3171f0bef2a27085b4b980e09f0c666fbdc58b944d97/
9.5M    /var/lib/docker/overlay2/3b470afdf8939b45159f3171f0bef2a27085b4b980e09f0c666fbdc58b944d97/
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo du -sh /var/lib/docker/overlay2/463ba63f79eb6b2f5466e7b71041bc346a8e9c4ebddd34d23422c719824a2340/
76M /var/lib/docker/overlay2/463ba63f79eb6b2f5466e7b71041bc346a8e9c4ebddd34d23422c719824a2340/
```

We can see the size that is close to 548M.

We also can save image to an output file.

```
[user@localhost ~]$ docker save -o neo4j.image.tar 8ed7463b8476
[user@localhost ~]$ du -sh neo4j.image.tar 
528M    neo4j.image.tar
```

We can extract the package file and check the sizes of files in the package.

```
[user@localhost neo4j.image]$ du -sh *
16K 2f0dd5fb60a940719a3e781133611cc64c2acded03bd47e04b0997fd0c1dae50
8.7M    73819037a38eabeb7c622533e4058c84f5ff106475a1aba78a278f8b36c172f7
309M    8d31d715b324a2ae3ccb1577e981d492f40e34db6371f0858da925ef02b5762e
12K 8ed7463b84760f09b1b86a732ee6f295baaadffe72ce4fdb7ad306fe5e096bbb.json
36K 966e726ff1d9be9dca68014cda6f1ecf974365c553b82ea3834fff5d73ea593e
70M a32776b9621e916e8714389b1037bf47253a2d3d1c806ad515623d2150c92485
60K d82868a318b95466f213136f81cd7258518744da72f46ca51b04b35f2351f46a
16K e62169d79fab44bebb0a455b01af5f636bace7673a1d38fc092daad77d51cd0e
141M    fe8014622f7933e178b9005deffda3eb4828703eb7eca93b5485232930e3916b
4.0K    manifest.json
```

We also can archive the folder `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/` to compare the size of the package to image files. The size is close to the image size either.

More helpful readings:

[docker image - merged/diff/work/LowerDir components of GraphDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56550890/docker-image-merged-diff-work-lowerdir-components-of-graphdriver/56551786#56551786),

[Where are Docker Images Stored? Docker Container Paths Explained](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/where-are-docker-images-stored-docker-container-paths-explained/),

[Overlay Filesystem](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt)

Answer (score 4):

check for the docker folder in `/var/lib`

the images are stored at below location:

```
/var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/imagedb/content
```

Comment: this has only sha256 folder

Comment: I think you meant to simply: `/var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/`. Also note that this is the case due to the fact that your Docker engine is using `overlay2` as the Storage Driver.

Comment: @toto' If you navigate inside your sha256 folder you'll see the hashed keys of your images. To identify exactly which image you're looking for, simply `docker image ls -a`. This essentially gives you the first 48 bits of the SHA256 hash key mapped to the repo and tags you've assigned to the particular image.

Answer (score 4):

Use `docker info` command to get the host settings of the docker including its storage path.

To get only the root path for the docker storage you may use:

```
docker info | grep 'Docker Root Dir:' | cut -d':' -f2 | sed 's/^ *//g'
```

That gives for the default `Ubuntu 22.04` and `docker --version` = `Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701` installation the path:

```
/var/lib/docker
```

listing the content of that directory with sizes by the command:

```
du -h -d 1 .
```

gives results (other directories):

```
444K    ./buildkit
4,0K    ./containers
4,0K    ./runtimes
16K     ./plugins
4,0K    ./trust
4,0K    ./tmp
100K    ./network
22M     ./image
2,0G    ./volumes
4,0K    ./swarm
9,0G    ./overlay2
```

To get docker root path suffixed with one of the directory name's you may add another `sed` at the end `sed 's/$/\/image/g'` for suffixing with the `/image`

command:

```
docker info | grep 'Docker Root Dir:' | cut -d':' -f2 | sed 's/^ *//g' | sed 's/$/\/image/g'
```

gives:

```
/var/lib/docker/image
```

command:

```
docker info | grep 'Docker Root Dir:' | cut -d':' -f2 | sed 's/^ *//g' | sed 's/$/\/overlay2/g'
```

gives:

```
/var/lib/docker/overlay2
```

Although names of the directories may seem self-explanatory the content of the images isn't stored in the `image` directory (22M size) but rather the information of the images. `/var/lib/docker/image/overlay2` in my case and especially the `/var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/repositories.json` file that has the names of the images and corresponding to them data about the `overlay2` layers.

The actual data of the images (and their layers) is stored in `/var/lib/docker/overlay2` (9,0G size)

Please note that the `overlay2` where the heavy data of the images is stored is a layerying system used by the docker but that layering system is one of many that docker may use (now or in the future). Therefore basing on the hard-coded paths may be fragile.

Especially if your intention is to expport/save the images into file you should look for the dedicated commands:

[What is the difference between save and export in Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655867/what-is-the-difference-between-save-and-export-in-docker)

With the command from the question as above you may even save all of your images into one file, compress it and then import them elsewhere by a single command.

If you want stick to the docker paths ie for creating backups I would recommend always use the root path for eg:

```
/var/lib/docker
```

generated by the `docker info` command especially you may have also important data inside:

```
/var/lib/docker/volumes
```

that is required by for eg. by the image of the database that uses a volume to persist the data.

Answer (score 3):

Environment: Windows 10 Pro, docker desktop 2.0.3.0 edge

right-click docker icon in system tray, select settings - advanced :

Disk image location (editable via the browser) :

C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual Hard Disks\DockerDesktop.vhdx

(it's there - Documents directory is hidden)

Comment: Is C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual Hard Disks\DockerDesktop.vhdx the image created by `docker build` command?

Answer (score 2):

On Fedora, Docker uses [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)) for storage if available. On my system `docker info` shows:

```
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: vg01-docker--pool
 Pool Blocksize: 524.3 kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74 GB
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Data file:
 Metadata file:
 Data Space Used: 9.622 GB
 ...
```

In that case, to increase storage, you will have to use LVM command line tools or compatible partition managers like *blivet*.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 2016, docker (DockerMsftProvider) uses the folder "windowsfilter" under docker root

```
>docker info
...
Storage Driver: windowsfilter
...
Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\docker
...
```

It uses the "tmp" folder under docker root to download the files and it deletes the files after extracting the downloaded files to "windowsfilter" folder.

Answer (score 1):

In 2021 on macOS the only possible solution is accessing Docker VM with bash and then see it's local structure:

1. `docker run -ti --privileged --pid=host debian nsenter -t 1 -m -u -n -i sh`
2. `cd /var/lib/docker/`

You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

On Debian Unstable/Sid,

`docker info` to find system-wide information.

images are stored at `/var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/imagedb/content` and

containers are stored at `/var/lib/docker/containers`

docker version `18.06.0-ce`, API version `1.38`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't resolve the question with Docker version 18.09 on macos using the above answers and tried again.

The only actual solution for me was using this `docker-compose.yml` configuration:

```
version: '3.7'
...
  services:
    demo-service:
      volumes:
        - data-volume:/var/tmp/container-volume

volumes:
  data-volume:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: /tmp/host-volume
```

After launching with `docker-compose up` I finally had `/tmp/host-volume` from macos shared as writeable volume from within the container:

```
> docker exec -it 1234 /bin/bash
bash-4.4$ df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
...
osxfs                488347692 464780044  21836472  96% /var/tmp/container-volume
```

Hope this helps others too.

Answer (score 0):

Images are stored inside `/var/lib/docker` and then under applicable `storage driver` directory.

Storage driver, being used, can be determined by executing `docker info` command.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone need it for scripting purposes, here is a one-line solution.

In POSIX shell, with PCRE enabled `grep`, try:

`DOCKER_ROOT_DIR="$(docker info 2>&1 | grep -oP '(?<=^Docker Root Dir: ).*')"`

In PowerShell:

`$DOCKER_ROOT_DIR="$(docker info 2>&1 | foreach {if($_ -match "Docker Root Dir"){$_.TrimStart("Docker Root Dir: ")}})"`

Note, when on Windows 10 (as of `10.0.18999.1`), in default configurations, it returns:

- `C:\ProgramData\Docker` in "Windows containers" mode
- `/var/lib/docker`, in "Linux containers" mode

Comment: On CentOS I had to use `DOCKER_ROOT_DIR="$(sudo docker info 2>&1 | grep -oP '(?<=Data loop file: ).*')"`, but in the end it is a file, not a directory

Comment: Are you sure it is not a directory? For me, `sudo ls "$(docker info 2>&1 | grep -oP '(?<=^Docker Root Dir: ).*')"` list the contents of this directory.