# Securing docker containers

Tags: security, deployment, docker, linux-containers

First of all let me say that I'm starting with docker and I haven't tried yet, in order to do that I would like to know if there is a way where I can prevent users from seeing docker containers file system (I presume the containers FS is located on plain files under the host like it happens in openvz containers, I'm wrong?), I would like to prevent certain users to see the containers file system and running docker commands on certain containers, is this possible? Can this be done using AppArmor or similar software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, see [Where are Docker images stored on the host machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234831/where-are-docker-images-stored-on-the-host-machine)

Without `sudo`, I get the following

```
[user@host] cd /var/lib/docker/graph/
-bash: cd: /var/lib/docker/graph/: Permission denied
```

Does that answer your question? Otherwise you might want to elaborate on your setup and what the users are user of, etc. But then your probably better off with experimenting a bit on your own before :)

Comment: As far as i can see file system is just a bunch of diffs and that suites me perfectly!, thanks