# What is the difference between save and export in Docker?

Tags: docker

I am playing around with [Docker](https://www.docker.io/) for a couple of days and I already made some images (which was really fun!). Now I want to persist my work and came to the `save` and `export` commands, but I don't fully understand them.

**What is the difference between `save` and `export` in Docker?**

Comment: I also wrote a blog post about this at http://tuhrig.de/difference-between-save-and-export-in-docker

Answer (score 200, accepted):

The short answer is:

- `save` will fetch an image : for a VM or a physical server, that would be the installation .ISO image or disk. The base operating system.

  It will pack the layers and metadata of all the chain required to build the image. You can then load this "saved" images chain into another docker instance and create containers from these images.
- `export` will fetch the whole container : like a snapshot of a regular VM. Saves the OS of course, but also any change you made, any data file written during the container life. This one is more like a traditional backup.

  It will give you a flat .tar archive containing the filesystem of your container.

Edit: as my explanation may still lead to confusion, I think that it is important to understand that one of these commands works with containers, while the other works with images.

- An **image** has to be considered as 'dead' or immutable, starting 0 or 1000 containers from it won't alter a single byte. That's why I made a comparison with a system install ISO earlier. It's maybe even closer to a live-CD.
- A **container** "boots" the image and adds an additional layer on top of it. This layer stores any change on the container (created/changed/removed files...).

Comment: Just for my clarification: Let's assume I have a running container where I did some changes (e.g. I made a new folder). Now I can make an image of this container (with `docker commit`). I can then `save` the image. Or I can `export` the container directly. And both ways (`save` the image and `export` the container) will have the same result?

Comment: Yes and no. The `export`will give you a flat .tar archive containing your container filesystem. `save` will pack the layers and metadata of all the chain required to build the image. You can then load this "`saved`" images chain into another docker instance and create containers from these images.

Comment: So `save` would be the option of choice if I want to copy an image on my good old USB-stick to share it with my friend who has no internet connection? So what is `export` then for? For what it is good to export the filesystem?

Comment: @ThomasUhrig You can use export to "flatten" the container to one layer/base image. Also you can use it to backup the container (f.e. data container). But this can be done without `export` function too.

Comment: Also , with `export` all the metadata will be lost , so in case you try to run the container with that image you have remention the CMD  and other metdata.  `save` worked fine for me but export was pain

Comment: I want to update my image to the latest version. The container that's running now has made some changes to the internal file system. After the upgrade, I want these changes restored. As I understand, both save/load and export/import will create a new image for me, which is not what I want. I want to use a new version of the image from dockerhub, but restore data from existing container. What's the best course of action?

Comment: @Dmitryz I think the simple answer is "neither". You should have a `Dockerfile` with the commands you want to run to customize the (now updated) base image for your needs.

Answer (score 38):

There are two main differences between `save` and `export` commands.

1. `save` command saves whole image with history and metadata but `export` command exports only files structure (without history and metadata). So the exported tar file will be smaller then the saved one.
2. When you use exported file system for creating a new image then this new image will not contain any `USER`, `EXPOSE`, `RUN` etc. commands from your Dockerfile. Only file structure will be transferred.
   So when you are using mentioned keywords in your Dockerfile then you cannot use export command for transferring image to another machine - you need always use save command.

Answer (score 11):

`export`: `container (filesystem)`->`image tar`.
`import`: `exported image tar`-> `image`. Only one layer.

`save`: `image`-> `image tar`.
`load`: `saved image tar`->`image`. All layers will be recovered.

From *Docker in Action, Second Edition* p190.

> Layered images maintain the history of the image, container-creation metadata, and old files that might have been deleted or overridden.

> Flattened images contain only the current set of files on the filesystem.

Answer (score 6):

The exported image will not have any layer or history information saved, so it will be smaller and you will not be able to rollback.

The saved image *will* have layer and history information, so larger.

If giving this to a customer, the Q is do you want to keep those layers or not?

Comment: so, an export is similar to a txt file with nothing written on it right?? @neil

Comment: it's like a text file with no undo buffer 8)

Answer (score 4):

Technically, save/load works with repositories which can be one or more of images, also referred to as layers. An image is a single layer within a repo. Finally, a container is an instantiated image (running or not).

Answer (score 2):

Docker **save** Produces a tar file repo which contains all parent layers, and all tags + versions, or specified repo:tag, for each argument provided from **image**.

Docker **export** Produces specified file(can be tar or tgz) with flat contents without contents of specified volumes from **Container**.

docker **save** need to use on docker image while docker **export** need to use on container(just like running image)

Save Usage

> docker save [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]
>
> Save an image(s) to a tar archive (streamed to STDOUT by default)
>
> --help=false       Print usage   -o, --output=""    Write to a file,
>   instead of STDOUT

export Usage

> docker export [OPTIONS] CONTAINER
>
> Export the contents of a container's filesystem as a tar archive
>
> --help=false       Print usage   -o, --output=""    Write to a file,
>   instead of STDOUT

Comment: Question is about difference between two commands not about generalized definition and usage!

Comment: @AbuShumon Sachin gave a clear explanation of what exactly `save` keeps that `export` doesn't, something that all the other answers refer to as some abstract 'metadata'.