# Installing elasticsearch docker image fails on command not found

Tags: elasticsearch, docker

I'm trying to install elasticsearch from an image I've created on another machine, however when I create the container it say that the command not found. I've understood that the command is not exported as part of the image, however I can't find the right command to spesify for it to work.

on Machine A I'm creating the image as such:

```
sudo docker pull elasticsearch
sudo docker save -o "elastic.image.tar" elasticsearch
```

On machine B I'm importing the image and trying to run it

```
sudo docker import "elastic.image.tar"
sudo docker run -d elasticsearch
```

on the docker run I get

```
docker: Error response from daemon: No command specified.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I've also tried the following commands:

```
sudo docker run -d elasticsearch elasticsearch
sudo docker run -d elasticsearch "/docker-entrypoint.sh elasticsearch"
sudo docker run -d elasticsearch "/usr/share/elasticsearch/docker-entrypoint.sh elasticsearch"
sudo docker run -d elasticsearch "/bin/bash"
```

None of them worked, all returned responce like:
docker: Error response from daemon: Container command 'XXX' not found or does not exist..

What is the right command to specify here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try `docker load -i elastic.image.tar` and call `docker run elasticsearch`. Check this question to know some [differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655867/what-is-the-difference-between-save-and-export-in-docker) between save/load and export/import.