# Is docker stateless?

Tags: docker, state, linux-containers

Is docker stateless? What I mean is does it store information about the running containers? It must and should, but the question is where is that information kept. I tried killing docker daemon and found that containers are still running. In fact I was not able to kill the process, instead it killed the existing process and forked a new one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where are docker images stored on the host machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234831/where-are-docker-images-stored-on-the-host-machine)

Comment: I know about about the location of the docker images where they are stored. What my question is how does docker know about it? Is there a way we can change the location? How about migrating live running containers from one docker host to another? What do you think on these lines. Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: docker inspect <containernameorid>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following command will kill and remove docker processes on your machine. I use it to periodically clean my docker host:

```
docker ps -qa | xargs docker kill | xargs docker rm
```

The following command will go further and purge downloaded docker images

```
docker images -qa | xargs docker rmi
```