# What is location of images pulled from Docker Hub via Docker for Mac

Tags: macos, docker, docker-for-mac, docker-desktop

***Note:** I know about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32605383/location-of-docker-images-downloaded-by-docker-1-9-1-on-mac-os-x) question, however, it is related to **Docker Toolbox** and not to **Docker Desktop for Mac** and it seems that each tool uses different location for storing Docker images locally

Where can I find a docker images that have been pulled from Docker Hub by means of Docker desktop for Mac?

I tried to verify that Docker is running by the following command.

```
docker run hello-world
```

As a result the Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub but I am not able to find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be in

```
$HOME/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/Docker.qcow2
```

with `Docker.qcow2` being the filesystem for the "vm" that Docker for Mac runs in.
See [issue 23437](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/23437#issuecomment-225224927).

That means removing the images ([thread 15194](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-doesnt-release-disk-space-used-by-library-containers-com-docker-docker/15194/3): `docker images -q |xargs docker rmi --force`) won't decrease the space occupied by Docker.qcow2 (and the disk space on the disk).
To the point you [start seeing aliases like this one](https://github.com/PostalMuttonchops/dotfiles/commit/8f4bbe7efeea5199c6d1661b85ebcf50268f27c1):

```
shrink-qcow2 () {
     mv ${1} ${1}.BACKUP && qemu-img convert -O qcow2 ${1}.BACKUP ${1}
}
```

Comment: Do I get it right that every time I pull an image, it becomes a part of the given file?

Comment: @pgiecek yes, it is a virtual disk (a file interpreted as a filesystem by the Mac VM)

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, you should find them here:

```
~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/
```

Comment: I cannot see any file/folder with a name 'hello-world' or something similar in there. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you see anything under `~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker`?

Comment: Yes, folder 'Data'. In that folder I see 'database', 'tasks' and 'com.docker.driver.amd64-linux' folders, none of which containing the image.

Comment: Odd. It should be in there somewhere. That's where Docker puts stuff.