# I can't find my Docker image after building it

Tags: macos, docker

I'm new to Docker, so please allow me to describe the steps that I did. I'm using Docker (not Docker toolbox) on OS X. I built the image from Dockerfile using the following command
 `sudo docker build -t myImage .`

Docker confirmed that building was successful.
`Successfully built 7240e.....`

However, I can't find the image anywhere. I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32605383/location-of-docker-images-downloaded-by-docker-1-9-1-on-mac-os-x), but the answer is for Docker toolbox, and I don't have a folder `/Users/<username>/.docker` as suggested by the accepted answer.

Comment: Do you actually need to know where the image is stored on the filesystem, or do you just want to check that Docker knows about it?  For the latter, just run `docker images`.

Comment: For the former, it's going to be in the docker host VM filesystem.

Comment: Look into ```docker save``` and ```docker load``` which allows you to save the image to a tar and load it again somewhere else. That way you have a tangeble actual image that you can move around with you from machine to machine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to list containers in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840409/how-to-list-containers-in-docker)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You would be able to see your docker images by the below command:

```
docker images
```

And to check which all containers are running in docker:

```
docker ps -a
```

Comment: Where is the location of the image files?

Comment: If all you need is an archive of the image, you can use [docker save](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/) like so `docker save myimage:tag | gzip > myimage_tag.tar.gz`. You can list your local images with `docker image ls`.

Comment: This would do the trick as well ```docker save myimage > image.tar```

Answer (score 17):

Local builds (in my case using buildkit) will create and cache the image layers but simply leave them in the cache rather than tell the docker daemon they're an actual image. To do that you need to use the `--load` flag.

```
$ docker buildx build -t myImage .
$ docker images

REPOSITORY       TAG                     IMAGE ID       CREATED             SIZE
```

Doesn't show anything, but...

```
$ docker buildx build -t myImage --load .
$ docker images

REPOSITORY       TAG                     IMAGE ID       CREATED             SIZE
myImage          latest                  538021e3d342   18 minutes ago      190MB
```

And there it is!

There actually is a warning about this in the output of the build command... but it's above all the build step logs so vanishes off your terminal without easily being seen.

Comment: I noticed this is happening to me now too and didn't used to. I wonder if something changed?

Comment: You may have updated to a more recent version of docker. I believe at some point they changed to using buildkit by default (don't quote me, though)

Answer (score 3):

To get list of Images

```
docker image ls
```

or

```
docker images
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the correct responses above that discuss how to access your container or container image, if you want to know how the image is written to disk...

Docker uses a Copy on Write File System (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) and stores each Docker image as a series of read only layers and stores them in a list.  The link below does a good job explaining how the image layers are actually stored on disk.

https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/

Answer (score 1):

As already said, after the **docker images**

this command will show you all the images you have locally.

i.e "somth like that"

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
codestandars        1.0                 a22daacf6761        8 minutes ago       622MB
bulletinboard       1.0                 b73e8e68edc0        2 hours ago         681MB
ubuntu              18.04               cf0f3ca922e0        4 days ago          64.2MB
```

now you should

`docker run -it` and the IMAGE ID or the TAG related to the repository you want to run.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to build the image, this can be done by the command below:

```
docker build -t myimage .
```

Once build you should be able to list the Docker image using the command below:

```
docker images
```

You can now locally save/export the image by using the command below:

```
docker save myimage > image.tar
```

Now you can import the image.tar in other Docker Managers and use it (e.g. you can use it in Synology's Container Manager by importing the image.tar file)

Answer (score 0):

Command to list the docker images is :

```
docker images
```

The default docker images will show all top level images, their repository and tags, and their size.
An image will be listed more than once if it has multiple repository names or tags.

[Click here for the screenshot for more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcyjX.png)