# What is the location of the docker image files on OS/X?

Tags: docker

There are several questions regarding how to *view* docker images on local machine including [I can't find my Docker image after building it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38464549/i-cant-find-my-docker-image-after-building-it?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The `docker images` command does report that an image was successfully created:

```
$docker images

REPOSITORY                                              TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
caffeonspark                                            cpu                 bd347271dc01        28 minutes ago      5.28 GB
```

This question is about the physical locations of the docker files - to do operations like copying/backups etc. How would the paths be found on OS/X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mac, Docker images are stored within the VM. See [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38532483/where-is-var-lib-docker-on-mac-os-x).

On Linux, Docker images are stored in `/var/lib/docker`, so backing up that directory should be sufficient.

I don't think you should be copying images from that directory. The normal way to share a built image between machines is with Docker Hub or with a private Docker registry. If you want to share images that are not published to a registry, you can simply share the Dockerfile.

Comment: Docker mounts a containers view of it's file system inside /var/lib/docker too so when backing up you don't want to cross to new file systems otherwise you will be backing up duplicate data.