# Locating a Directory after Docker Pull

Tags: python, macos, docker

I'm trying to reproduce results from [this](https://github.com/gasparian/CRNN-OCR-lite) repository using docker.

I have completed the pull using

```
docker pull gasparjan/crnn_ocr:cpu
```

and run it using

```
docker run --rm -it -v /home:/data -p 8004:8000 gasparjan/crnn_ocr:cpu
```

To execute the following command:

```
python3 predict.py --G 0 --model_path %PATH_TO_MODEL% \
--image_path %PATH_TO_IMAGES% \
--validate --num_instances 512 --max_len 21
```

I require the `PATH_TO_MODEL` how do I locate the `model.json` file that was just pulled?

I've tried using solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32605383/location-of-docker-images-downloaded-by-docker-1-9-1-on-mac-os-x) but unfortunately I'm unable to locate the pulled directory.

I've also tried downloading the repo from Github and then passing the location of the `model.json` file and it yields an error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/Luke/Downloads/CRNN-OCR-lite-master/models/OCR_IAM_ver1/model.json'
```

Please Advise.

*I'm using macOS Big Sur.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running this line:

```sh
docker run --rm -it -v /home:/data -p 8004:8000 gasparjan/crnn_ocr:cpu
```

you will be dropped inside the container's command line. You can look around with `ls`:

```sh
➜  sudo docker run --rm -it -v /home:/data -p 8004:8000 gasparjan/crnn_ocr:cpu
root@0e2914bb1aad:/# 
root@0e2914bb1aad:/# ls -la
total 124
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root  4096 Apr 27 13:36 .
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root  4096 Apr 27 13:36 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root     0 Apr 27 13:36 .dockerenv
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root  4096 May 14  2019 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr 12  2016 boot
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Apr 27 13:35 data
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root   360 Apr 27 13:36 dev
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root  4096 Apr 27 13:36 etc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr 12  2016 home
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root  4096 May 14  2019 lib
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root  4096 May 14  2019 lib64
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jan 22  2019 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jan 22  2019 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 May 14  2019 models
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jan 22  2019 opt
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root  8034 May 11  2019 predict.py
dr-xr-xr-x 378 root root     0 Apr 27 13:36 proc
drwx------   1 root root  4096 May 14  2019 root
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root  4096 May 14  2019 run
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root  4096 Jan 22  2019 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jan 22  2019 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root     0 Apr 27 13:37 sys
drwxrwxrwt   1 root root  4096 May 14  2019 tmp
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root  8572 May 10  2019 train.py
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root  4096 Jan 22  2019 usr
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root 23446 May 10  2019 utils.py
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root  4096 Jan 22  2019 var
root@0e2914bb1aad:/# ls -la /models
total 55892
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 May 14  2019 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root     4096 Apr 27 13:36 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      490 Jan 24  2019 arguments.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11482392 Mar 24  2019 checkpoint_weights.h5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 34189880 Jan 24  2019 final_model.h5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11482392 Jan 24  2019 final_weights.h5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      136 Jan 24  2019 loss_history.pickle.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    31729 Jan 24  2019 model.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    15524 Jan 24  2019 model_summary.txt
```

So the file is at `/models/model.json` inside the container!

As for the images, I couldn't find any images inside the container. I think you are meant to supply your own. In that case, look at the command (`/home:/data`). This is a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) which means that `/home` on your PC and `/data` inside the container are the same folder now.

So I would try adding some images to your PC's `/home` folder and then, inside the container, running:

```sh
python3 predict.py --G 0 --model_path /models/model.json \
--image_path /data \
--validate --num_instances 512 --max_len 21
```

Answer (score 2):

I am a newbie at this. But I think I have a solution.

I pulled the docker image and it seems like if you replace **%PATH_TO_MODEL%** with **models** in your python3 command - it works!

Here is what the final command looks like:

```
python3 predict.py --G 0 --model_path models \
--image_path %PATH_TO_IMAGES% \
--validate --num_instances 512 --max_len 21
```

If you do `ls` once you are inside the docker container, you will be able to see all the directories.

```
__pycache__  boot  dev  home  lib64  mnt     opt         proc  run   srv  tmp       usr       var
bin          data  etc  lib   media  models  predict.py  root  sbin  sys  train.py  utils.py
```

I am not sure if this helps, but let me know.