# How to run docker image in windows

Tags: linux, windows, docker, boot2docker, docker-registry

I have pulled the phishing frenzy image from repo using [this command.](http://www.phishingfrenzy.com/resources/install_with_docker)

I used this command

```
docker pull b00stfr3ak/ubuntu-phishingfrenzy
```

The image is downloaded fine and works I checked using this command.

```
docker images
```

Now for running the image I am issuing this command

```
run -d -p 80:80 b00stfr3ak/ubuntu-phishingfrenzy
```

but nothing happens , I want to know how I can run a downloaded image from docker in windows and where it is stored as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command should be **[`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)**, not `run`

And the image is stored [in your `/var/lib/docker/images` folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25978888/6309), in the boot2docker VM.