# Failed to start key/value store when setting up Memgraph using Docker and mounting to a different disk

Tags: memgraphdb

I am attempting to set up Memgraph using Docker, and I want to mount my mount point inside Docker to store the data on a different disk from where Docker is installed. However, whenever I try to do this, it fails to start and I receive the warning "`Failed to start key/value store.`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the default location of the Docker data directory is solution for this problem. The Docker daemon has a `--data-root` property that can be used to specify a different location for storing data.

Steps for chaining it are:

1. Stop the Docker service.
2. Edit the Docker service file and add the `--data-root` property with the desired location.
3. Restart the Docker service.

More information about the `--data-root` property can be found in the [official Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/). There is also related discussion on how to change the default location for Docker volumes [here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36014554/how-to-change-the-default-location-for-docker-create-volume-command).

It's recommended to use named volumes instead of bind volumes with Memgraph. Named volumes provide a way to manage the data without worrying about the underlying file system path.