# Docker image location

Tags: docker

What is the physical location of docker image in ubuntu machine?
I am using ubuntu 14.04.
a.  Distributor ID: Ubuntu
b.  Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
c.  Release:        14.04    Codename:       trusty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where are docker images stored on the host machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234831/where-are-docker-images-stored-on-the-host-machine)

Comment: I tried all the options in mentioned link but didn't solve my problem

Comment: Why do you need to know this?

Comment: Not really my requirement, but just curious to know how docker is managing space allocation and other thing intrnally

Answer (score 2):

Docker images aren't stored as one file like you see using `docker images`.

Docker image *layers* are stored in `/var/lib/docker`, there are sub folders of storage drivers. If you run `docker info`, you should see `Storage Driver: aufs`, and I'm assuming that your install defaults to aufs.

So your path is going to be `/var/lib/docker/aufs/*layerfolders*`

Comment: I went to /var/lib/docker/aufs/*layerfolders*. Sub-directory of /var/lib/docker/aufs/ has diff, layes and mnt folder in which diff and mnt has container info anf layer has all files of 1 kb each. And my image sixe is almost 2.4 GB. So, still bot clear about the location.

Comment: Sorry! Don't know how else to help, not exactly sure what you are looking for. You can run a `du -h` on the /var/lib/docker folder to see what is taking up space. You might get more clarity from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234831/where-are-docker-images-stored-on-the-host-machine