# Cant find output of docker import

Tags: docker, docker-image

I used the following command to create a docker image

```
cat exampleimage.tgz | docker import - exampleimagelocal
```

The image was created successfully. But I am unable to find where this image is located. I can run the image by using the command

```
docker run exampleimagelocal
```

I tried to find the file using

```
locate exampleimagelocal
```

But it didn't return any result. Can someone tell me where docker has stored this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you need to know where this is stored on disk but typically it will be in the /var/lib/docker directory with the image ID as a folder name depending on what OS your running. See this question for details [Where are Docker images stored on the host machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234831/where-are-docker-images-stored-on-the-host-machine). To find the image ID you can run `docker inspect exampleimagelocal` and look for the image key in the outputted JSON. Or you can find a short ID by running `docker images`.

Hope this helps

Dylan