# Where does the output for "docker -build" go?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a sample docker image.  When I run the following command:

```
docker build -t sample .
```

Where does the docker image go?

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:boron

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: I believe it answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234831/where-are-docker-images-stored-on-the-host-machine

Answer (score 26):

Use:

```
docker images
```

to see it

Example:

```
REPOSITORY     TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
sample         latest              c660b762fcd1        5 days ago          1.46GB
```

Comment: I swear these were not showing up in my Docker Desktop application, but running the command from the directory I ran the build from seems to show them. Now they are showing in Docker Desktop  I noticed in VSCode with the Docker extension you have to click the option for "Show dangling images" if none are showing up there, but show up when you run `docker images`.

Answer (score 8):

They get stored as a series of layers in your Docker root directory. On Linux, it's `/var/lib/docker`.

Answer (score 1):

after building you docker image run

```
docker image ls
```

then pick the image name you are interested (from first column) and run

```
docker image inspect <image name>
```

you will see there is about that image including location