# docker image location on mac

Tags: macos, docker

i built docker image using maven plugin.
it is named as springio/gs-spring-boot-docker.

Successfully tagged springio/gs-spring-boot-docker:latest

I believe there should be a file on my Mac with name springio/gs-spring-boot-docker.
However I am not able to find out.

Comment: Are you using Docker toolbox on mac or Docker for Mac?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234831/where-are-docker-images-stored-on-the-host-machine

Comment: it is docker for mac: