# Create a docker image in a specific directory

Tags: docker

The question is. There is docker with already installed and running images. How can I install new images to another directory? All Internet rummaged, but nothing was found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the closest to your question is to export the images from the local "docker system" to the filesystem so that it will be possible to load it into local docker image registry in future or possibly transfer to another machine or something.

**docker save** saves the images into an arbitrary place on the filesystem (you can tell it where to save) [Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_save/)

**docker load**  loads the images
[Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/#parent-command)

If you want to find more information about an exact place where the docker manages images, consider reading  [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234831/where-are-docker-images-stored-on-the-host-machine)