# Docker Containers all gone after reboot

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04

I had changed the directory to store containers and images as `/data/docker`.And it work successfully in the coming one year.

However, after I reboot the system (Ubuntu 16.04), a disk partition `/dev/sdb4` was broken，which was mount to `/data/docker`. And the broken partition lead to the system come into **emergency mode**. I run a command `fsck -y /dev/sdb4` to repair it and restart again.

After restarting，all work normally as before except docker. It is amazing that all my container and almost images were missing. When I run `docker container ls -a`,I got nothing. When I run `docker images`,I only got one list `mysql               5.6                 7edb93321b06        5 months ago        256MB`.But I had **4 containers** and **some (more than one) images** before. In other words,they were gone after reboot.

In addition，when I run `sudo du -h /data/docker/volumes`,I got:

> 6.8M /data/docker/volumes/b35a0a2be6a1d10693e891f0b5c7dfa6e27a34b6a61384e6db79ac06df4bde36/_data/mysql
>   636K    /data/docker/volumes/b35a0a2be6a1d10693e891f0b5c7dfa6e27a34b6a61384e6db79ac06df4bde36/_data/performance_schema
>   116M    /data/docker/volumes/b35a0a2be6a1d10693e891f0b5c7dfa6e27a34b6a61384e6db79ac06df4bde36/_data
>   116M    /data/docker/volumes/b35a0a2be6a1d10693e891f0b5c7dfa6e27a34b6a61384e6db79ac06df4bde36
>   4.0K    /data/docker/volumes/4bfb7ca010e869edd409ee14aa3a8b9ec70ec144a1b1586e792a8f87f9d5a9b2/_data
>   8.0K    /data/docker/volumes/4bfb7ca010e869edd409ee14aa3a8b9ec70ec144a1b1586e792a8f87f9d5a9b2
>   4.0K    /data/docker/volumes/d24ddf0126cef08bc3ff8bf75e79e76375b1e6cfa70c646d3173554d78555aeb/_data
>   8.0K    /data/docker/volumes/d24ddf0126cef08bc3ff8bf75e79e76375b1e6cfa70c646d3173554d78555aeb
>   4.0K    /data/docker/volumes/c22f29c1ab50c2973e6e1cc3e1ea64ad7a253741d44a290df3789fbf1e4c3a05/_data
>   8.0K    /data/docker/volumes/c22f29c1ab50c2973e6e1cc3e1ea64ad7a253741d44a290df3789fbf1e4c3a05
>   4.0K    /data/docker/volumes/985f51b406657eacbd70dfe7d0bd0502287c783a389ae34fa36d70b5c98e94a3/_data/#innodb_temp
>   84K /data/docker/volumes/985f51b406657eacbd70dfe7d0bd0502287c783a389ae34fa36d70b5c98e94a3/_data/sys
>   32K /data/docker/volumes/985f51b406657eacbd70dfe7d0bd0502287c783a389ae34fa36d70b5c98e94a3/_data/mysql
>   84K /data/docker/volumes/985f51b406657eacbd70dfe7d0bd0502287c783a389ae34fa36d70b5c98e94a3/_data/test
>   1.4M    /data/docker/volumes/985f51b406657eacbd70dfe7d0bd0502287c783a389ae34fa36d70b5c98e94a3/_data/performance_schema
>   165M    /data/docker/volumes/985f51b406657eacbd70dfe7d0bd0502287c783a389ae34fa36d70b5c98e94a3/_data
>   165M    /data/docker/volumes/985f51b406657eacbd70dfe7d0bd0502287c783a389ae34fa36d70b5c98e94a3
>   3.1G    /data/docker/volumes/b445468b292cff4531429b7a9883a825fc794327a46672ec518e7765050437e5/_data/newProject
>   6.8M    /data/docker/volumes/b445468b292cff4531429b7a9883a825fc794327a46672ec518e7765050437e5/_data/mysql
>   387M    /data/docker/volumes/b445468b292cff4531429b7a9883a825fc794327a46672ec518e7765050437e5/_data/project
>   636K    /data/docker/volumes/b445468b292cff4531429b7a9883a825fc794327a46672ec518e7765050437e5/_data/performance_schema
>   4.0G    /data/docker/volumes/b445468b292cff4531429b7a9883a825fc794327a46672ec518e7765050437e5/_data
>   4.0G    /data/docker/volumes/b445468b292cff4531429b7a9883a825fc794327a46672ec518e7765050437e5
>   4.2G    /data/docker/volumes

It means that some of data  is not lost.

**How can I repair it and find them back ？**

Comment: If you have one, restore the latest backup. Actually the volumes are more valuable, the images should not be hard to find somewhere else.

Comment: You've mentioned that you made path change to where Docker store images. After the reboot, have you checked if Docker looking at the same folder?

Comment: @PraveenP When I run `docker info |grep 'Docker Root Dir'`，I can get
 `Docker Root Dir: /data/docker`

Comment: @Henry It is sad that I run these containers for a long time without any backup.The only image(`mysql:5.6`) left is the base image which I pull down from the public repository.

Comment: Well at least the contents of the container still exist, you need to copy them to a new one. For the images, can you check in the [`/var/lib/docker`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234831/where-are-docker-images-stored-on-the-host-machine) if they are still there, that's where it would be at.