# docker-machine can't see local docker

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I have xubuntu-based linux.
I have the docker installed on it.
But for my infrastructure I need to use `docker-machine` as a manager. 
The problem is that `docker-machine` cant see my images as it by default look into `~/.docker`. I do tried to set `MACHINE_STORAGE_PATH` variable to those that are used by `overlay2` storage driver(from this [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234831/where-are-docker-images-stored-on-the-host-machine)) but none of them are going to work. Even if my docker have 1 running machine, docker-machine see none.

```
>docker-machine active
No active host found
```

And:

```
>docker info
Containers: 17
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 16
Images: 15
Server Version: 18.09.0
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: c4446665cb9c30056f4998ed953e6d4ff22c7c39
runc version: 4fc53a81fb7c994640722ac585fa9ca548971871
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.16.13-galliumos
Operating System: GalliumOS 3.0
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 3.791GiB
Name: galliumos
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Product License: Community Engine
```

How to configure `docker-machine` to see my docker images?

This is simplified structure of my `/var/lib/docker`:

```
/var/lib/docker
├── builder
│   └── fscache.db
├── buildkit
│   ├── cache.db
│   ├── content
│   │   └── ingest
│   ├── executor
│   ├── metadata.db
│   └── snapshots.db
├── containers
│   ├── 077f50df3a86911d1d715f6658e9a0984b16041ebdf7a9497c90a7185c63c17a
│   │   ├── 077f50df3a86911d1d715f6658e9a0984b16041ebdf7a9497c90a7185c63c17a-json.log
│   │   ├── checkpoints
│   │   ├── config.v2.json
│   │   ├── hostconfig.json
│   │   ├── hostname
│   │   ├── hosts
│   │   ├── mounts
│   │   │   └── shm
│   │   ├── resolv.conf
│   │   └── resolv.conf.hash
├── image
│   └── overlay2
│       ├── distribution
│       │   ├── diffid-by-digest
│       │   │   └── sha256
│       │   │       └── fa83472a3562898caaf8d77542181a473a84039376f2ba56254619d9317ba00d
│       │   └── v2metadata-by-diffid
│       │       └── sha256
│       │           └── f75e64f96dbc610a00722afa3826745952db8d1416f6405e7e87c20868b9f542
│       ├── imagedb
│       │   ├── content
│       │   │   └── sha256
│       │   │       └── d40668baebcb80ab9c13667d2c62ca359b52bba417415f257313b98fed17d1ef
│       │   └── metadata
│       │       └── sha256
│       │           └── d40668baebcb80ab9c13667d2c62ca359b52bba417415f257313b98fed17d1ef
│       │               └── parent
│       ├── layerdb
│       │   ├── mounts
│       │   │   └── fec9fa167f8f6944ca24c1c9fdffe8142392922ad9f8967f095ffdee536e4025
│       │   │       ├── init-id
│       │   │       ├── mount-id
│       │   │       └── parent
│       │   ├── sha256
│       │   │   └── eb91e8adb4541f0df58f6d896fee1355e04c0984b3104da1038178b8d6649b6b
│       │   │       ├── cache-id
│       │   │       ├── diff
│       │   │       ├── parent
│       │   │       ├── size
│       │   │       └── tar-split.json.gz
│       │   └── tmp
│       └── repositories.json
├── network
│   └── files
│       └── local-kv.db
├── overlay2
│   ├── 81957d0e7cac6b00a103bad4da4f12e8103f56f358902aa4c39d9d9b8164917a
│   │   ├── diff
│   │   │   └── go
│   │   │       └── bin
│   │   │           └── all-in-one-linux
│   │   └── link
│   ├── ffbbee81aeec171e1a70b27f3c3fc7ace6c0ca33dbfdd6d390b406d34b1c8b6d-init
│   │   ├── diff
│   │   │   ├── dev
│   │   │   │   ├── console
│   │   │   │   ├── pts
│   │   │   │   └── shm
│   │   │   ├── etc
│   │   │   │   ├── hostname
│   │   │   │   ├── hosts
│   │   │   │   ├── mtab -> /proc/mounts
│   │   │   │   └── resolv.conf
│   │   │   ├── proc
│   │   │   └── sys
│   │   ├── link
│   │   ├── lower
│   │   └── work
│   │       └── work
│   └── l
│       ├── 2N57ZPCEPUQ3TVUAH5HY2M526N -> ../ffbbee81aeec171e1a70b27f3c3fc7ace6c0ca33dbfdd6d390b406d34b1c8b6d/diff
│       └── ZOEHN3DWY3C3JS3UHQ634XJRAB -> ../114a646d7a311920e7ee0d958e6d480036303b7e9b220d056ac3823fb8d431bf/diff
├── plugins
│   ├── storage
│   │   └── blobs
│   │       └── tmp
│   └── tmp
├── runtimes
├── swarm
├── tmp
├── trust
└── volumes
    ├── 2ace0452ee4d6b6094ec704c3873843f6bb4e29c5d712241b15060da7d36e945
    │   └── _data
    └── metadata.db
```

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17454

Comment: https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/1435

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with `docker-machine` in this setup?

Comment: I want to manage with it my local docker instalation

Comment: What do you mean by "manage"?

Comment: stop/deploy/start my containers, using unified tool `docker-machine`

Comment: `docker-machine` doesn't do that.  It manages local or remote VMs that run the Docker daemon, and _that_ starts/stops containers.  It's not a preferred solution on most platforms these days, and you never needed it for everyday use on Linux hosts.  The mode you're describing doesn't really make sense: there's nothing for `docker-machine` to actually manage in this scenario.

Comment: So it can manage local docker until it use net addr socket instead of unix socket?