# What files are produced by Docker's build command and where are they stored?

Tags: docker, windows-10, dockerfile

I've installed [Docker Engine Community edition for Windows](https://hub.docker.com/search/?type=edition&offering=community&operating_system=windows) on a computer running Windows 10 Pro.

I ran `docker build --tag my-python-app .`

Which files did the command produce and where are they located?

Also, I've read a [Where are Docker images stored on the host machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234831/where-are-docker-images-stored-on-the-host-machine).

Lastly, the simple Dockerfile contains:

```
FROM python:alpine3.7
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD python ./index.py
```

Comment: `docker build` doesn't produce any output beyond the built image, so the question you linked should have all of the details (it has a pretty comprehensive set of answers).  Also note that you generally shouldn't be poking around in Docker's internals, and the other answer is "it doesn't produce any files outside of private Docker space".

Comment: @DavidMaze you mentioned the `docker build` doesn't produce any output beyond the built image.  What is this build image (e.g. filetype, filename, set of files, etc.) and where is it located?  I'm not really trying to poke into Docker's internals.  Re "it doesn't produce any files outside of private Docker space" that's ok, I'm ok with that.  However, I think we can run the Docker save command to generate Docker images.  Does this mean the save command looks into Docker's private space to generate the Docker images?

Comment: Once `docker build` builds an image, it's just like any other image you've `docker pull`ed, and the linked question discusses where it's stored; the actual details are somewhat installation-specific.  The tar file `docker save` generates is an export and [its file format is lightly documented](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.39/#operation/ImageGet), but that's not the "default" way to work with images.

Comment: Hmmm...it's still not too clear to me.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55656335/3731622) refers to the Docker guides.  The Docker guides say the built image from `docker build` is "in your machine's local Docker registry."  Where is this "local Docker registry" on my machine & what is the "built image" it refers to?