# The location where are Docker images stored on the host machine doesn't exist

Tags: docker

I have issues with installation on my Mac Mojave computer. I need to install a package from https://github.com/manifold-lang/pymanifold which is saved as docker image. I have downloaded the image but I don't know where it went. It was supposed to go to a standard docker root directory [as discussed in a different stachoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234831/where-are-docker-images-stored-on-the-host-machine/37642236#37642236).

stripped terminal snippet

```
user:bin user-13$ docker info
...
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
...
user:/ user-13$ cd var/lib/docker
-bash: cd: var/lib/docker: No such file or directory
```

full terminal snippet

```
user:bin user-13$ docker info
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 1
Server Version: 17.03.1-ce-rc1
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 4ab9917febca54791c5f071a9d1f404867857fcc
runc version: 54296cf40ad8143b62dbcaa1d90e520a2136ddfe
init version: N/A (expected: 949e6facb77383876aeff8a6944dde66b3089574)
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.9.13-moby
Operating System: Alpine Linux v3.5
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 1.952 GiB
Name: moby
ID: J3ZK:NC6K:Z24D:OFVF:ILXT:EYFH:S54X:EUTO:43PK:ZOVN:KCO7:PODS
**Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker**
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 16
 Goroutines: 26
 System Time: 2019-07-21T15:04:44.905694923Z
 EventsListeners: 1
No Proxy: *.local, 169.254/16
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
user:/ user-13$ cd var/lib/docker
-bash: cd: var/lib/docker: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It seems like the answer you link to answers this: the images are inside the VM and you can't directly access them from the host.  (You shouldn't be trying to directly access them anyways; their format can be hard to understand and there are a half-dozen incompatible variants.)

Comment: This problem is resolved. The instructions for pymanifold were not clear for me so I misunderstood on part.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where are Docker images stored on the host machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234831/where-are-docker-images-stored-on-the-host-machine)

Comment: I have quoted this one: " Where are Docker images stored on the host machine? " But the answer there is not working for my problem. The folders mentioned in that question do not exist on my machine.