# Do docker images and volumes location's change depending on the host environment?

Tags: docker, docker-volume, docker-container

Is true and why, depending on the host environment, e.g. Linux, Windows or OSX, Docker images and Docker volumes can be stored in different locations (with respect to the root file system of the host)?

Can someone bring an example?

Comment: This post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234831/where-are-docker-images-stored-on-the-host-machine has all your answers.

Comment: Yes but nobody explains why. I understand that each operating system uses a different docker storage driver, but I'm searching for the underlying motivation of this decision. Why should the storage location vary based on the host environment?

Comment: `devicemapper` doesn’t need special kernel support, but it’s slow and inflexible.  `overlay2` needs kernel support which is mainstream within the past 1-2 years.  Environments inside VMs can be different from environments without.  You shouldn’t be poking around in `/var/lib/docker` in any case and this makes no practical difference to almost all programs.