# Docker: Where is the image stored in Ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I created a Docker image.
Its repository name is docker-hello-world and its Docker Image ID is e127d87570f9.

I understood that it should be placed in /var/lib/docker/overlay2/, but when I open this folder this is what I see:

```
$ sudo ls -alF /var/lib/docker/overlay2/
total 40
drwx------ 10 root root 4096 Dec 28 17:28 ./
drwx--x--x 14 root root 4096 Dec 28 01:35 ../
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Dec 28 01:35 0a6ee9708ef2529b105ae04ee9279877f23a3408d81ea58433e34f9e278fd90e/
drwx------  4 root root 4096 Dec 28 17:28 17c9c50edb4ecc6ffd47a688720dfe1b7f5d407ac9eb8f2b0ec5e62eccf9400f/
drwx------  4 root root 4096 Dec 28 01:36 5fd838043c830a61c6efeeec62c1c1cca9d500556faca5870c526b0a34766a63/
drwx------  4 root root 4096 Dec 28 01:35 5fd838043c830a61c6efeeec62c1c1cca9d500556faca5870c526b0a34766a63-init/
drwx------  4 root root 4096 Dec 28 17:28 820dc021f10e31423aaba6ada86fbc06a03aa531d277c5de598e101dd2cd9881/
drwx------  3 root root 4096 Dec 28 17:28 cfc4379bcf9885bd305fae0f85368941b863bb7533db4d088ffcd397b86f2182/
drwx------  4 root root 4096 Dec 28 17:28 fa4ffb5887a1cbde6b3e58505119043ec891754bb3d797f1aedf68292c52477b/
drwx------  2 root root 4096 Dec 28 17:28 l/
```

Do you know where to look for the image file?

Comment: Why do you need to know this? If you want it in a file you can always execute a `docker save -o output_file e127d87570f9` and you will have it independently of where Docker keeps it.

Comment: please check below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234831/where-are-docker-images-stored-on-the-host-machine

Comment: In fedora 29, the image file is stored in `/var/lib/docker/overlay2` by default. see [answer-66256522 of Where are Docker images stored on the host machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234831/where-are-docker-images-stored-on-the-host-machine/66256522#66256522)