# how to find directory of a kafka in pod in GCP?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I'm using Kubernetes on Google Cloud Platform; I installed the Kafka image in a pod, but when I try to make communication between producer and consumer with Kafkacat nothing is working.

I want to find the directory kafka in pod.

[image: this picture is the deployement of kafka broker]

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to achieve by finding its location?

Comment: FWIW, you may find Helm Charts or open source Operators as easier ways to setup Kafka in k8s

Comment: What do you mean by "location of wurstmeister/kafka" -- what output are you looking for?  Why specifically do you want to use bash here?  How is that PNG file related to the question?  Can you include any relevant application source code  in the question (maybe replacing the image)?

Comment: i want to deploy  kafka in kubernetes ? i

Comment: I am sorry , i ask about the directory of kafka installed in pod ,i find it in OPT/KAFKA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The containers running inside a pod are actually run by the docker daemon (assuming docker is the chosen container runtime for this Kubernetes deployment) of the host machine.

So in case of GCP the host machine will be the worker VM where the pod is scheduled by Kubernetes.

You can get to know which worker VM by looking at the node by running the command:

`kubectl get pod pod name -o wide`

Hence the image will be stored in the file system of the host machine. The exact path depends on the OS distribution of the host machine.

This is discussed here [Where are Docker images stored on the host machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234831/where-are-docker-images-stored-on-the-host-machine?rq=1)

Comment: my question is about directory of kafka in pod , i find it in /opt/kafka