# Where on my drive is my docker image? (It's not under /)

Tags: linux, docker, filesystems

I recently installed a docker image that is 26.3GB uncompressed (as reported by its listing under `docker images`)

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, and Dolphin reports my free hard drive space as 3GB. However, when I run QDirStat (a disk usage analyzer) it tells me that the total space the `/` subtree is taking up is only 25.6GB. The partition Linux is on is 60GB, so I can only conclude that the docker image is not anywhere under `/`. So where is it?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234831/where-are-docker-images-stored-on-the-host-machine

Answer (score 0):

From terminal:

`find / -name <insert name off container> -size G <insert file size here>`

This instruct the Linux find command to search from the root of the OS for the name of your container and simultaneously searches by size (in GB). If this doesn’t yield any results, try only searching by name or only by size.... the size will need to be exact, as will the name to find it correctly.

You can also run this to display all containers to get the accurate name.

> Docker ps -a

Are you by chance instructing Docker to save to a separate partition or drive? This may indicate why you couldn’t find it under /.