# Where is the location of images that i pulled from docker hub on my windows?

Tags: docker

I am a newbie in docker. I pulled some images and want to see the location of these images.

I already look at docker disk image location. This is the path where my images is located  -->>

C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\vm-data

i went through this specified path. There was DockerDesktop.vhdx file but

nothing more. How can i see the location of my images on windows that i pulled from docker hub ?

Comment: Use the docker command line to list the images

Comment: i already have 4 images. i just wonder the location of these images

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19234831/4636715 This question is not specific to Windows, but includes answers for Windows, too.

Comment: @mnamver, the images would be inside the docker vm. But I've used docker images extensively, and never cared about seeing them on the filesystem. Why do you need to see them? All interaction with docker imags is done through the docker cli and docker daemon