# Pulling docker image on mounted directory

Tags: docker

I am using a machine with os `ubuntu-18.05` in arm platform. It has some space issue and I want to work with docker images.
Usually, when I work on this machine I mount a directory and perform memory expensive operations there.

**Is there any way I can pull image in host machine and make it work?**

Example: I have mounted directory `/home/test-mount`, now instead of storing docker image and it's graph in location mentioned here [Where are Docker images stored on the host machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234831/where-are-docker-images-stored-on-the-host-machine) I want to efficiently pull, store and use image at path `/home/test-mount`, such that it can be easily switched to actual path.

Comment: I don't get what mounted directories have to do with memory expensive operations, or do you mean disk read/write intensive?

Answer (score 0):

Stop docker and make sure the following can be found in in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```json
{
"data-root": "/home/test-mount"
}
```

Now restart docker